# exit bat file after an execution in cmd

Tags: java, windows, batch-file, ant, cmd

Im running a selenium TestNG script using ANT in eclipse. The execution completes but the cmd prompt stays there even after the execution when i try to run the bat file from java. But when i run the bat file by double clicking it, the cmd exit after execution. Here below are the code to invoke the bat file and content of bat file:

```
Runtime.getRuntime()
                        .exec("cmd /c start run.bat", null, new File("C:\\Users\\nvithushan\\Desktop\\HSBC\\gen\\seleniumwebdriver\\HSBC_Demo"));
```

This is the content of the batch file.

```
@echo off
echo exectution starting
start ant
exit
```

Any help

Answer (score 1):

It should be sufficient in your exec to do `cmd /c run.bat` and in your batch file just do `ant.bat` or `call ant.bat`. By definition the start command starts a separate cmd process. Note also the documentation:

> If [the command you run] is an internal cmd command or a batch file
>   then the command processor is run with the /K switch to cmd.exe. This
>   means that the window will remain after the command has been run.

Comment: When i remove the START from the java code the bat file is not starting. The program just terminate without  executing the bat file. Thanks for stopping by

Comment: Try adding a `pause` at the of your batch files so you can see what is going on.